# Why is the ora-archive-state column a varchar2 4000 chars?

Tags: oracle, archiving

Can someone explain why Oracle made the ora-archive-state column a varchar2 of 4000 chars?  When using the in-database archiving feature of Oracle 12c, when the column is 0, the record is visible.  When anything other than 0, the record is hidden.

What's the purpose of having the extra 3999 chars when simply setting the column to 1 accomplishes the goal?  I'm doubting Oracle is just wasting the space.

Answer (score 1):

Because it allows you to mark "archived" rows differently: you can update ORA_ARCHIVE_STATE to different values, for example: `to_char(systimestamp,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ssxff')`
to set it to the date of archiving. And later you can analyze archived records by this column.

> I'm doubting Oracle is just wasting the space.

Varchar2 doesn't waste space. It is variable-length character string. Ie varchar2(4000b) doesn't mean it will use 4000 bytes, or varchar2(4000c) ~ chars. That's just maximum allowed column length